# Dual Boot which Windows partitions should be removed?

Tags: dual-boot, window, partitioning

I want to reinstall my Windows 10. If I am correct I need to delete the **ntfs** Files System, that is the partition **sda2** and **sda3**, right ? I should not delete **sda1** because it is the partition used for booting the system, right ?

After reinstalling Windows will Grub be working fine or do I need to fix it and how ?

[image: Gparted Image]

Comment: Don't delete any partitions. Just reinstall Windows, and then use the `boot-repair` tool from the Ubuntu website.

Comment: Well actually I want to delete the partitions.

Comment: Delete `sda2` then. `sda3` is a Lenovo recovery partition, which might come in handy.

Comment: @Devid : Just format the sda2 partition with ntfs and select this partion when reinstalling Windows ! :)

Comment: Is the Lenovo partition sda3 so important, because I would also like to delete that ? After I install Windows again should I just use boot repair on a live CD ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First format the sda2 partition with ntfs.
Reinstall Windows - select this partition.
Afterwards reinstall GRUB boot loader.

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.

On Live desktop - open a terminal.
Execute the following commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda6` = system partition

When you want to keep Windows, it is recommended to keep the sda3 Lenovo partition as well.
It might contain important tools for recovering vendor specific - Windows related functionality.
In case there is no Windows entry in GRUB menu, boot Ubuntu ... open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: @Devid : Did you get Windows and after that GRUB installed successfully ? :)

Comment: Not yet, but soon. I am confident though that your answer is the best, that is why I accept it. Thanks